# How to disable horizontal scrolling on OS X Yosemite's Preview?

Tags: preview, macos

As stated in the question, how do I disable horizontal scrolling on Preview when the page obviously fits and there is over horizontal overflow?

I am scrolling with my touchpad, and with two-finger scroll I inevitably move a little sideways while scrolling. This little jerk to the left/right is rather annoying to me and I would like to know if there are any ways to prevent the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: There are many builds of Yosemite. If you open the terminal app and type `sw_vers` what version and build are you running?

Comment: ProductName: Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.3
BuildVersion: 15D21

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem and I solved it by cloning and building a fork of the Scroll-Reverser tool, whose repository is below.

https://github.com/dawncold/Scroll-Reverser

As you can see in [this commit](https://github.com/dawncold/Scroll-Reverser/commit/194dcdf618b32283413fc8bde825bb279d92fb2f) the author made a little patch in the tool in a way such that if you check the `reverse horizontal scrolling` option, it actually **disables** it instead of reversing it.

This is also explicitly stated by the author of the patch [here](https://youth2009.org/post/disable-horizontal-scroll-on-macos/).

You will need XCode to build the project and to generate the corresponding app.

Just as general information (the original author deserves it), the original Scroll-Reverser tool, which was doing just reversing instead of disabling, can be found [here](https://github.com/pilotmoon/Scroll-Reverser)